# Convert String to hex little endian format in C++

Tags: string, c++-cli, hex, int, endianness

I have a string 2290348
I need it to display as ACF22200 (little endian)

Because the input 2290348 is passed in via a form in textbox, I have tried to read it as string (eg. `this->textBox1->Text`) and convert it to int (eg. `Convert::ToInt32(this->textBox1->Text)`).
afterwhich, i converted it to hex via `ToString("x")` which i manage to get 22F2AC
I appended 00 to 22F2AC and gotten 0022F2AC still as string
now i'm stuck in converting 0022F2AC to ACF22200

Answer (score 1):

While still an `int`, you could use e.g. [`htonl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert it to "network" byte order.

```
#include <winsock2.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 0x22F2AC;
    printf("x = 0x%08x\n", x);
    printf("htonl(x) = 0x%08x\n", htonl(x));
    return 0;
}
```

The program above prints:

```
x = 0x0022f2ac
htonl(x) = 0xacf22200
```